# Received fatal alert: bad_certificate RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured

I am using the RestAssured library to make calls to certain REST API's

These are https endpoints and I tried using the "relaxedHTTPSValidation()"  method provided in RestAssured to bypass SSL validation

My request looks something like

```
RequestSpecification req = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().body().post();
```

I keep getting the error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
```

Doeas anyone have an idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Is your URL public so that I can try it out?

Comment: An alternative way to do this is to add the cert of the hostname to the trust store.. cacerts or jssecerts.

Comment: There can be many reasons- check this link if that helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site

Comment: There can be many reasons.Check below link if tht helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? We had the same issue before with an early version. After updating it to the latest the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Un-synched same java version b/w the client and server.
2. compatibility issues with different versions of SSL & TLS v1, where as client handles only using SSL v3).