# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: handshake_failure when using JMeter with SSL (JDK8)

Tags: ssl, https, jmeter, java-8, java-7

I am writing a JMeter test plan to connect to SSL port (Tomcat Connector). I receive a SSLHandshakeException (handshake_failure) when connecting to SSL port using any of the three JMeter SSL client implementations (HttpClient4, HttpClient3.1, Java) on JDK8 (1.8.0_51). If I use JDK7 (1.7.0_75) - everything works as expected.

```
Client JDK: HotSpot 1.8.0_51
Client OS: Mac OSX 10.10.2
JMeter version: 2.13

Server: Tomcat 7.0.63 (latest)
Server SSL CipherSuite: RC4-SHA
Server SSL Protocol: all
Server Java: OpenJDK 1.7.0_79
```

Here are some things I have already tried:

(1) I tried replacing the JCE Unlimited Strength JARs, as suggested on a similar question:
[SSLHandshakeException while connecting to a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site)

No changes in error messages or logfile, JDK8 client would not connect to the SSL server.

(2) I turned on debugging as described here: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https. Starting JMeter with `JVM_ARGS` set to `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose`. The logfile (attached below) did not hint any reasons what the issue might be.

(3) I tried specifying the HTTPS procotol, e.g. `-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3`. No luck. **SSLv3** was disabled or cipher were not matching:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)`

(4) I tried disabling **SNI**, e.g. `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`. No luck either.

So, I am forced to use the **JDK7** for now, until I can get my JMeter to run with **JDK8**, and I'd like to fix that.

So, the issue is in how JDK8 handles SSL clients differently from JDK7. Also, the server (Tomcat Connector) would need to support appropriate ciphers and protocols, but that's out of my control for now.

Here are relevant logs:

```
X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Agents (clients) 1-2, setSoTimeout(0) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
GMT: 1422637724 bytes = { RandomCookie:  GMT: 1422637724 bytes = { 71, 27, 101, 246, 26, 99, 64, 213, 53, 66, 156, 66, 118, 137, 247113, , 226, 86, 121, 189, 207, 175, 98, 46, 64, 242, 48, 19, 30, 66, 251, 120, 125, 249, 63, 114, 254, 246, 5, 168, 17, 190, 214, 228, 90, 165128 }
Session ID:  , 113, {}
157, 211, 230, 144, Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
145, 63, Compression Methods:  { 238, 0178 }
Session ID:  {}
 }
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
Agents (clients) 1-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 237
Agents (clients) 1-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 237
Agents (clients) 1-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Agents (clients) 1-2, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
Agents (clients) 1-2, called closeSocket()
Agents (clients) 1-2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Agents (clients) 1-2, called close()
Agents (clients) 1-2, called closeInternal(true)
Agents (clients) 1-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
Agents (clients) 1-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
Agents (clients) 1-1, called closeSocket()
Agents (clients) 1-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Agents (clients) 1-1, called close()
Agents (clients) 1-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Here's the stacktrace I get in JMeter logfile:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, how do I make JDK8 client in JMeter talk to SSL port using protocols and ciphers allowed by the server.

Thanks!

**Edit: Added SSL Labs test results**

```
Protocols
    TLS 1.2    Yes
    TLS 1.1    Yes
    TLS 1.0    Yes
    SSL 3      No
    SSL 2      No

Cipher Suites (sorted by strength as the server has no preference; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)
    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)      WEAK        128

Clients
    Java 6u45    No SNI 2    TLS 1.0    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5) No FS    RC4    128
    Java 7u25                TLS 1.0    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5) No FS    RC4    128
    Java 8u31                TLS 1.2    TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5) No FS    RC4    128
```

Comment: The server may be too old, only supporting insecure protocols and/or ciphers. If it is accessible via internet check it's TLS capabilities using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: Whats your jmeter version? Can be a version mismatch.

Comment: @Ushani - Apache JMeter 2.13 as stated in the question.

Comment: @Robert - The server is Apache Tomcat 7.0.63 (the latest). I will check the SSL connector details and test with SSLlabs. Thanks.

Comment: @nevenc: OK, the list of supported ciphers is really bad. Only RC4 is supported and RC4 is insecure and deprecated and therefore disabled in current Java 8 versions (as recommended by RFC7465). The server administrator has applied outdated recommendations. Conclusion: Your problem is the server admin.

Comment: @robert Thanks Robert. That's what I figured out after digging a bit more. I did remove CipherSuite from Tomcat Connector definition, and allowed all ciphers. My Java8 JMeter client was able to speak to the server, but SSL-Labs grading is pretty bad now. Do you have a good reference recommendation for SSL connector ciphers (recent one)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after some digging, and ideas in the comments, it boils down to the Tomcat configuration. Tomcat Configuration only allowed `RC4-SHA`, which is insecure and not supported in Java 8 anymore, per [RFC7465](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465) (thanks [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert) for the reference).

I got JMeter to work on Java8, by updating server SSL configuration and removing `RC4-SHA`-only cipher, and allowing all default cipher suites, e.g. dropping `SSLCipherSuite="RC4-SHA"` from `server.xml` Tomcat configuration file.

Adding stronger security encryption ([JCE Unlimited Strength Policy](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)), will allow for better cipher suites and stronger encryption. You will need to be aware of US exporting rules though.

I will need to make decision as to which ciphers we want to support. That depends on the clients that we are expecting to connect to our SSL Tomcat connector. One client is definitely our JMeter test client, and there are few other RESTful clients that will be connecting, written in various languages and for various platforms.

Hopefully this discussion helps out others and shed some light.

I would like to edit this answer to add recommended (at the moment) TLS protocol and CipherSuite settings.

I found some great discussion on [Mozilla ServerSide SSL Configuration](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS):

**Modern Compatibility**

```
Ciphersuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
Versions: TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
RSA key size: 2048
DH Parameter size: 2048
Elliptic curves: secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1 (at a minimum)
Certificate signature: SHA-256
HSTS: max-age=15724800
```

**Intermediate Compatibility**

```
Ciphersuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
Versions: TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2
RSA key size: 2048
DH Parameter size: 2048 (see DHE and Java for details)
Elliptic curves: secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1 (at a minimum)
Certificate signature: SHA-256
```

... and others

Thanks everyone that chimed in.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I solved this problem on a mac, as gleaned from [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site):

1. Download updated security jars from Oracle - these ones are for Java 8:
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
2. Unzip the downloaded zip file.
3. Go to the security folder in your java home directory:

   ```
   cd $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security
   ```
4. Back up the following jars from this folder:

   - US_export_policy.jar
   - local_policy.jar
5. Replace with jars from zip file.
6. Restart Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same exception in JDK7_u80. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: handshake_failure. Even after I replace jars in security folders with JCE jar.

I installed new version JDK8_u92 and set the environment path to newly installed Java8. And jmeter issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it based on the inputs given in the above post. My two cents in resolving the issue:

1. Try to hit the URL from chrome and click on lock button and view certificate.
2. Look for the https protocol supported (e.g. TLS v1.2)).
3. Verify from if your java version supports. If not, update java.
4. In jmeter properites file, update the property to

   `https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2`
5. Restart jmeter.

The above procedure worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that allows JMeter to connect to insecure endpoints (or those that use old or not secured enough protocols):

- Find your JRE;
- Open `jre\lib\security\` folder;
- Make a backup copy of `java.security` file;
- Edit `java.security` file and comment out all lines that disable insecure algorithms - search for 'disabledAlgorithms' string (don't forget to comment out both lines in multiline settings), they look like:

`jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024, \
    DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224`

- save the file and restart JMeter.

Java connections are now allowed to use old protocols, so JMeter can properly work.

**REMEMBER it's security!**

These settings are global, and will affect **all** programs that use the same JRE. If you found this fix works and useful for your system, **DO** create a copy of your JRE, and set a path to it in `jmeter.bat`. Return your global settings from backed up copy of `java.security` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similiar issue with Jmeter 3.2 and JRE 8 and add below properties in Jmeter JNDI Properties, its working fine for me:

```
java.naming.security.principal  
java.naming.security.credentials    
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.security_protocol   
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_enable_verify_host  
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_trusted_certs   
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_password    
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_auth_only   
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_trace   
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_debug_trace 
com.tibco.tibjms.naming.ssl_identity
```

Comment: Could you explain how the parameters (I guess this should actually be key-value-pairs?) solve the problem and if all of them are needed?

Comment: its is key value pair of Jmeter JNDI properties..though I can see the response in Jmeter , but debug log still show Handshake exception message.