# Jmeter SSL Exception when connecting to https

Tags: ssl, https, jmeter, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect to https site from jmeter and I am getting the below response data in the View Results Tree:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure 
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)

To connect to the https site there is a certificate which can be exported to .cer format. I tried exporting the certificate and then adding it to Jmeter_home\bin and installing it. Also from Jmeter Option->SSL Manager I selected the certificate. But the above attempts didn't work.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009083/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failure-when-using-jmeter-with-ss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: handshake\_failure when using JMeter with SSL (JDK8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32009083/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failure-when-using-jmeter-with-ss)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't understand `cer` format, as of current version (4.0) it supports the following formats:

- [JKS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html)
- [PKCS12](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/tsec_ssl_jsp_pkcs12.html)

You can convert the certificate using [Keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) or [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/). Once done you can add `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` system property pointing to the .jks or .p12 certificate and your outgoing requests will be encrypted. More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: I got the .pfx file which I converted to JKS and update the system.properties. Still I get the same response Response code: Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Also in logs it looks like the jks is not loaded  2018-05-10 17:02:58,187 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2018-05-10 17:02:58,187 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore