# Get request handshake_faliure:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

While sending a get request to www.sunnyportal.com the error code appeared in the console, it is as follows:

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at personal.Project.GetUrl.getReq(GetUrl.java:25)
at personal.Project.GetUrl.main(GetUrl.java:34)
```

I tried the following pages with no luck:

+[Received fatal alert: handshake_failure through SSLHandshakeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception)

+[How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659360/how-to-solve-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-error)

Here is my code:

```
package personal.Project;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import java.io.InputStream;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    import java.net.URL;

    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import java.net.URLEncoder;

    public class GetUrl {

        private String url = "https://www.sunnyportal.com/Templates/ChartValues.aspx";

private String charset = "UTF-8";  // Or in Java 7 and later, use the constant: java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()
private String login = "<>";
private String password = "<>";

public String getReq() throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{
    String query = String.format("login=%s&password=%s", 

            URLEncoder.encode(login, charset), 
            URLEncoder.encode(password, charset));

        URLConnection c = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        InputStream response = c.getInputStream();  

        return response.toString();
}
public static void main (String args[])
{
    GetUrl data = new GetUrl();
    String getString = null;
    try {
        getString = data.getReq();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.println( getString );
}

}
```

Would love help with this problem, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sunnyportal.com that server negotiates only one ciphersuite, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, which uses AES with 256-bit key.

If you are using **Oracle Java** to use any symmetric cipher above 128 bits, which includes AES 256, you must **download and install the JCE Unlimited Strength** Jurisdiction Policy Files for your version. For the currently supported version, 8, near the bottom of the general download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html it links to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html . For older versions search finds http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html .

PS: dupe of [SSLHandshakeException while connecting to a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site) although I'm not sure you could have been expected to find that.

Comment: Now that I have the file is there a certain folder that I have to put it into? or do I just up and run it?

Comment: @PeterSparks you unzip it (on modern Windows opening in explorer does this) and put the two 'jar's into your JRE's `lib/security` directory replacing the 'limited' ones. Where your JRE is varies quite a lot depending on your platform and (often) how you installed it, which you didn't say. There's also a README file inside the zip that tries to explain this, but still doesn't cover all possible cases.