# https connection timeout issue with JMeter and Java 8

Tags: java, jmeter

I am getting an error when running a JMeter script with Java 8.

I have tried changing the "JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" in my Java 8 as well. [SSLHandshakeException while connecting to a https site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350120/sslhandshakeexception-while-connecting-to-a-https-site)

Still I could not resolve the issue.

Comment: Try what this article recommends: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https (could be TLS issue for example)